# Mount EBS voulme across the EC2 machines

Tags: shell, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I have any ebs volume mounted to an ec2 instance. 
Am taking an image so that whenever i need to create a new instance i use the image.I can make the ebs volume re mount if the ec2 reboots.
But if i have to use the same image across allec2 machines its not possible because, when we do lsblk the default mounts may not be the same

lsblk of one ec2 machine:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  30G  0 disk /data
```

lsblk of another machine:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:80   0  30G  0 disk /data
```

now inspite of xvdb or xvdf i have to mount my ebs volume.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Label the master volume with a unique label using `e2label`.

Then, in `/etc/fstab`, instead of specifying the device by its block device name, specify `LABEL=your_label`.